# Concatenating and Pattern Matching SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as follows in SQL:

**Accounts**, containing

```
id     zip     city 
----   -----   ---------------
121    20085   Los Angeles
```

**Customer**, containing

```
user id   zip  
-------   ------
121       20085
```

**Addr**, containing

```
zip     city-state
-----   ----------------
121     Los Angeles, CA
```

I want to add an extra column in `Accounts` called `location` which will be a concatenated field that will take `city` from `Accounts` concatenate it with `city-state` from `Addr` by matching the `city`.

I cannot do the regular join as all the `zip` in `Accounts` are not there in `Addr` so I will loose many records, but the table `Customer` contains all the `zip` and `user id` so I think I can make use of that.

The output desired:

**Accounts**, containing

```
user id    zip    city              location 
-------    -----  ----------------  ----------------
121        20085  Los Angeles       Los Angeles;Los Angeles, CA
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this:

```
SELECT
  `c`.`user_id`, 
  `c`.`zip`, 
  `a`.`city`,
  CONCAT_WS( ';', `c`.`city`, `aa`.`city-state` ) AS `location`
FROM
  `Accounts` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN
  `Addr` AS `aa`
     ON
        `aa`.`zip`, `a`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
  `Customer` AS `c`
     ON
        `c`.`user id`, `a`.`id`
```

Comment: yes I want to concatenate two column City from Account and City-State from Addr by matching the city and concatenating both the fields and adding it to the Accounts table as showed in the above example

Comment: In the first join one is zip and other is id LEFT JOIN
  `Addr` AS `aa`
     ON
        `aa`.`zip`, `a`.`id what does that mean i dint get

Comment: Well I assumed that 'zip' was your primary key on the Addr table

Comment: some cities are getting linked with same city like for eg one of the row contains san francisco; san francisco, ca and other row contains just san francisco this is mayb because of zip codes. Can we do pattern matching so that all the entries for san francisco will contain san francisco; san francisco, ca in the loaction column